# Trouble replicating HTML code in a Smarty foreach

Tags: php, html, smarty3

I have a block of code I'm trying to replicate using a foreach, but I can't get around on how to do this the code is as follows:

```
     <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">Content</a>
          </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
          <div class="panel-body">
            <table class="table">
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil text-primary"></span><a href="">Articles</a>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-flash text-success"></span><a href="#">News</a>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-file text-info"></span><a href="#">Newsletters</a>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment text-success"></span><a href="#">Comments</a>
                  <span class="badge">42</span>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

This is part of a collapsible sidebar, and ideally the EG and the AG have a section to themselves

```
This is the array I'm trying to display on this block

    $smarty -> assign('produtosGC1',
    array('EG' => array('Tipo ST','Tipo LP','Tipo SG','Hollowbody'),
    'AG' => array('Clássicas','Aço')
    ));
```

This is my attempt, almost there:

```
      <div class="panel panel-default">

        {foreach $produtosGC1 as $produto}
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">{$produto@key}</a>
          </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in"> 
          <div class="panel-body">
            <table class="table">
             {foreach $produto as $item}
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <a href="">{$item}</a>
                </td>
              </tr>
             {/foreach}
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
        {/foreach}
      </ul>
    </div>
```

The thing is, the second title (the AG) does not link properly with its sub-categories and doesn't collapse correctly

Edit:changed the question title because it wasn't correct

Comment: I'm glad you're "almost there". What's the problem? What's your question?

Comment: I did some edits, I think it's better explained now

Comment: I've never used smarty and I don't know exactly how your collapsible menus are working. But I do notice that your classes are being duplicated. Are you sure they are all meant to be `collapseOne`? If they need to be unique you'll need to have a counter of some kind and increment the value in both the div class and the data toggle href

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After tinkering and thanks to @Darren H's tip I got it working and it's as follows:

```
{foreach $produtos as $produto}
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse{$produto@index}">{$produto@key}</a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse{$produto@index}" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <table class="table sidebar">
          {foreach $produto as $item}
          <tr>
            <td>
              <a href="{$item}">{$item@key}</a>
            </td>
          </tr>
          {/foreach}
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
    {/foreach}
```